# JSON array out of order

Tags: python, json, reactjs, django, rest

I have a React/Django application where users can answer multiple choice questions. I have the "choices" array rendered onto the UI in this exact order.

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question_text": "Is Lebron James the GOAT?",
        "choices": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "choice_text": "No",
                "votes": 0,
                "percent": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "choice_text": "Yes",
                "votes": 1,
                "percent": 100
            }
        ],
    }
```

When I select a choice in development mode, I send a request to Django to increment the votes counter for that choice and it will send back a response with updated votes in the same order. When I try to select a choice in production mode using npm run build, the order becomes switched.

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question_text": "Is Lebron James the GOAT?",
        "choices": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "choice_text": "Yes",
                "votes": 1,
                "percent": 50
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "choice_text": "No",
                "votes": 1,
                "percent": 50
            }
        ]
    }
```

I thought the order of JSON array must be preserved. Can anyone explain why this is happening? I'm almost positive that this issue is originating from Django. Here is the function view on Django.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def vote_poll(request, poll_id): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)

        selected_choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=request.data['selected_choice_id'])
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        poll_serializer = PollAndChoicesSerializer(poll)
        return Response({ 'poll': poll_serializer.data })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering) option in your Choice model Meta if you want to have consistent order.

```py
class Choice(Smodels.Model):
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']
```

From docs:

> **Warning**
>
> Ordering is not a free operation. Each field you add to the ordering incurs a cost to your database. Each foreign key you add will implicitly include all of its default orderings as well.
>
> If a query doesn’t have an ordering specified, results are returned from the database in an unspecified order. A particular ordering is guaranteed only when ordering by a set of fields that uniquely identify each object in the results. For example, if a name field isn’t unique, ordering by it won’t guarantee objects with the same name always appear in the same order.